# Backing up Windows 8 OS and files without invalidating license

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot

I am trying to dual boot my PC. It came with a valid version of Windows 8, Is there a way to backup the actual OS with the valid license? So that whenever I try reinstalling it again I don't get an invalid Win8 version message etc.. What utilities do I need?

Comment: Do you have the serial key?

Comment: The license key is embedded in firmware.  Windows 8 installation will automatically detect it.  You don't have to do, nor back anything up, unless you want to.

Comment: That is good news, but how do I obtain a copy of the OS though. Do I download it from somewhere? make a backup? say if I wiped my drive, where do I get the windows 8 to reinstall it?

Comment: surely I don't have to buy it? since what you purchase is the license and as you mentioned the license is embedded in the hardware..